# WordPress Membership Plugin Advice

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, user-roles, membership

I need a plugin to allow every users to register and login to my site. I'm looking for a free alternative. I've google and found the following two alternative:

1. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/
2. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

Which of theme you think is better or do you have any other plugin in your knowledge than can better acheive this???

Comment: Close vote as _not constructive_: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: I was only trying to ask people who have experience things, I'm new to wordpress. In the tags, there is <plugin-recommendation>. I suppose recommendation from people always exhibit opinions and debates.But if u says Close vote, then Close Vote from my part as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin for that, it is build in.

Go to **General Settings** (`wp-admin/options-general.php`) and activate the checkbox for *Anyone can register*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also look into Paid Memberships Pro for adding membership functionality to a WordPress site. Fully GPL:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-memberships-pro